# Why need to reboot the system after starting service of Active MQ 5.6.0 on linux redhat

Tags: linux, activemq-classic

I have created one activemq service by using following steps in linux.

```
# ln –s /home/STI/SIServer/apache-activemq-5.6.0/bin/linux-x86-64/activemq \
    /etc/init.d/activemq
# chkconfig –add activemq
```

Started activemq service by following command:

```
# chkconfig activemq on
```

But i need to reboot system to make activemq working.

Also, by stopping service using #chkconfig activemq off , service is not stopping.
I need to forcefully kill pid of activemq.

Please provide inputs , how i can resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

chkconfig only controls which run levels a service will run at, it doesn't start the service. Use `service activemq start` to start it and `service activemq stop` to stop.

Comment: After even using service activemq start, Active MQ pid is generated. but Active MQ does not get started properly

Comment: @kavita you probably need to run the service command using sudo. Also check your logfiles to see if they tell why the service crashed.